# Unexpected result using money_format

Tags: php, wordpress, currency, money-format

I'm trying to assign the output of a custom wordpress field to `$number` and then use `$number` inside money_format. My expected output is `£ value_in_number`, but I'm actually getting `value_in_number £`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $number = the_field( 'amount_raised' ); 
    setLocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
    echo money_format('%n', $number) . "\n";
?>
```

If i assign an actual value to `$number` I get my expected result, but adding `the_field( 'amount_raised' );` switches the symbol and value around. amount_raised is a number field.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `en_GB.UTF8`. That works for me. With `en_GB` I get only the number

Comment: Or try `setLocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB');`, perhaps?

Comment: can you paste a var-dump of number? for me is working if $number is a string or int

Comment: `var_dump($number)` returns `NULL`.

I think I'm assigning the variable incorrectly. It seems that `$number = the_field( 'amount_raised' );` is just outputting the value of `amount_raised`, rather than assigning it to `$number`